# BigQuery get and aggregate data joined using values from an array

Tags: google-bigquery

Say I have 2 tables

`owners`

| owner | car_ids |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1, 2, 3 |
| Sue | 3, 4, 5 |

`cars`

| car_id | price | last_driven |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 200 | 2022-01-02 |
| 3 | 300 | 2022-01-03 |
| 4 | 400 | 2022-01-04 |
| 5 | 500 | 2022-01-05 |
| 6 | 600 | 2022-01-06 |

And I want to get the sum of the price of all the cars per driver, and when they last drove, so the data looks like:

| owner | total_worth | last_driven |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 600 | 2022-01-03 |
| Sue | 1500 | 2022-01-06 |

How would I do that? I can't figure out how to aggregate over values in a different table joined by values in the array field.

So far what I've got is

```
SELECT distinct
  owner,
  car_id,
  cars.worth,
  cars.last_driven,
FROM `owners` cross join unnest(card_id) as car_id
join `cars` cars on cars.owner = owner
```

but this won't aggregate the data, it'll only output each row.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select owner, sum(price) total_worth, max(last_driven) last_driven
from owners, unnest(car_ids) car_id
left join cars using(car_id)
group by owner
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This is great @Mikhail; I have a small follow up. You're doing `max` on last driven to get that value, but what if there are other fields that don't need to be aggregated? For instance, if I wanted to add a field from the owner table `owner.email_address`? Do I have to either aggregate on it in some way or group by it?

Comment: usually in such cases I use something like `array_agg(struct(last_driven, email_address) order by last_driven desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*` instead of `max(last_driven) last_driven` OR just adding `any_value(email_address) email_address` to the select list.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below query:

```sql
SELECT owner, SUM(price) total_worth, MAX(last_driven) last_driven
  FROM cars c JOIN owners o ON c.car_id IN UNNEST(o.car_ids)
 GROUP BY 1;
```

###### Query results:

| owner | total_worth | last_driven |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 600 | 2022-01-03 |
| Sue | 1500 | 2022-01-06 |

###### Sample tables

```sql
WITH owners AS (
  SELECT 'John' owner, [1, 2, 3] car_ids
   UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Sue', [4, 5, 6]
),
cars AS (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(o1, o2, o3)
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 6)) car_id WITH OFFSET o1,
         UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(100, 600, 100)) price WITH OFFSET o2,
         UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-01-01', '2022-01-06')) last_driven WITH OFFSET o3
   WHERE o1 = o2 AND o2 = o3
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaytiger, I have a small follow up question written above under the other answer.